# Panda's pd.where function behaviour with nullable condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

when using Pandas'`Series.where` function, I came across the following behaviour: it seems that the result of applying `Series.where` with a nullable condition depends on the value of the argument `inplace`.

Compare the two following snippets of code:

```
s = pd.Series(range(6))
cond = [True, False, pd.NA, False, True, True]
t = s.where(cond=cond)
```

gives

```
t
0    0.0
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    4.0
5    5.0
dtype: float64
```

whereas

```
s = pd.Series(range(6))
cond = [True, False, pd.NA, False, True, True]
s.where(cond=cond, inplace=True)
```

gives

```
s
0    0.0
1    NaN
2    2.0
3    NaN
4    4.0
5    5.0
dtype: float64
```

It seems like a design choice. Indeed when looking at the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.0.2/pandas/core/generic.py#L9640) we see the following :

```
# make sure we are boolean
 fill_value = bool(inplace)
 cond = cond.fillna(fill_value)
```

which means that null values in the condition get filled differently depending on the value of `inplace`.

So my question is: **what am I missing and why would such behaviour be desirable (assuming it is not just a bug) ?**

As per the documentation, the argument `inplace` is used to indicate whether to perform the operation in place on the data.
I certainly wouldn't have expected its value to change change the result of the operation itself.
(Of course, the same discrepancy is observed when using `Series.mask`, since `Series.mask(cond)` is defined as `Series.where(~cond)`)

**Edit:** As @Corralien points out, to observe the same behaviour with `Series.mask` and not get an exception, first convert the condition to Panda's boolean data type, ie replace the condition above by
`cond = pd.Series([True, False, pd.NA, False, True, True]).astype(pd.BooleanDtype())`
This is the kind of conditions you get when you define filters from a dataframe with nullable columns of type `pd.StringDtype()` for example.

Comment: Do you really observe the same behavior with `Series.mask`. It should raised a `ValueError` exception, no? (cause pd.NA)

Comment: @Corralien Thank you for commenting. You are right, indeed, that as I have posted it, you would get an exception with 'Series.mask' However in my situation, I am dealing with condition series that are of pandas 'pd.BooleanDtype()' which behaves slightly differently than Python's boolean and in particular support NAs. Hence, in my question above, if you write 'cond = pd.Series([True, False, pd.NA, False, True, True]).astype(pd.BooleanDtype())' instead, you do not get an exception when taking the negation of this, and hence you do in fact observe the same behaviour.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: @Corralien I am able to work around this behaviour by dealing with nulls before calling these functions, but unfortunately no one replied to this question. I strongly suspect this is an error so if I don't get an answer here soon, I will just raise an issue on Pandas GitHub (but there are about 3.4k open ones!). 
What I find puzzling is that this does not look like your typical bug, e.g a loop that you don't enter as expected or something like that. This is a straightforward assignment and I'm really curious what they had in mind when writing this.

Comment: After analyzing the code (for a long time...), I don't understand the use of ` fill_value = bool(inplace) `. I must admit that it is totally incomprehensible to me, I do not understand the logic behind all this. If you decide to open an issue, post the link here please. I really have no solution to this problem :(